# Jade: parenthetical ERROR

Tags: node.js, pug, agents-jade

When I compiled my code:

```
script
(function() {
  var uv = document.createElement('script'); 
  uv.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  uv.async = true;
  uv.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'widget.uservoice.com/MY_API_KEY.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s);
});
```

The compiler shows the error as:

```
Jade:9
7|    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
8|    s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s);
9|    });
```

missing ) in parenthetical

Any help would be appreciated, i'm not very good at Jade framework

Answer (score 0):

Here we have up  to 3 errors:

- Jade Syntax x2

  1. Missing dot before the script tag.
  2. Bad indentation
- Javascript x1

  1. The function  is never gets called/executed because a missing () at the end.

---

```
.script  // the dot
  (function() {    // indent  all the js in the script tag.
    var uv = document.createElement('script'); 
    uv.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    uv.async = true;
    uv.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'widget.uservoice.com/MY_API_KEY.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s);
  })(); // missing ()
```